# How to separate Pandas datadrame by date from datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like that:

```
    0      2017-07-01 00:00:00  12.19  ...          0.601               222.2
1      2017-07-01 00:05:00  12.24  ...          0.525               193.9
2      2017-07-01 00:10:00  12.24  ...          0.555               179.2
3      2017-07-01 00:15:00  12.29  ...          0.697               164.8
4      2017-07-01 00:20:00  12.36  ...          0.767               173.6
```

I need to separate it by seasons (basically months). Tried to do like this:

```
df_son = df.loc['2017-09-01' : '2017-11-30']
print (df_son)
```

Result is empty dataframe with all columns but no rows.

Or this:

```
df_son = df['2017-09-01':'2017-11-30']
print (df_son)
```

Result is this error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [2017-09-01] of type str
```

So, how to do that? Datetime object seems to be okay

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to accomplish it

```
df[df['date'].astype('datetime64').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').between('2017-07-01', '2017-08-01')]
```

```
x   date                           b       c      d
0   0   2017-07-01 00:00:00     12.19   0.601   222.2
1   1   2017-08-01 00:05:00     12.24   0.525   193.9
2   2   2017-09-01 00:10:00     12.24   0.555   179.2
3   3   2017-10-01 00:15:00     12.29   0.697   164.8
4   4   2017-07-01 00:20:00     12.36   0.767   173.6
```

```
    x   date                       b       c      d
0   0   2017-07-01 00:00:00     12.19   0.601   222.2
1   1   2017-08-01 00:05:00     12.24   0.525   193.9
4   4   2017-07-01 00:20:00     12.36   0.767   173.6
```